# Sharing data structures between 2 Python processes

Tags: python, data-structures, python-3.x, share, rpc

I have 2 applications/process/scripts running with Python 3: there is some easy RPC mechanism to share lists, tuples and data structures between this 2 separate processes ?

To be precise this 2 processes are working locally, on the same machine, but a generic solution that can also work with remote processes will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start up the processes using multiprocessing, you're able to share `Array` and `Value` variables across the process boundary.

Check out [this python doc page](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) on using `shared memory` and `multiprocessing`

> ...
>
> ```
> from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array
>
> def f(n, a):
>     n.value = 3.1415927
>     for i in range(len(a)):
>         a[i] = -a[i]
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     num = Value('d', 0.0)
>     arr = Array('i', range(10))
>
>     p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
>     p.start()
>     p.join()
>
>     print(num.value)
>     print(arr[:])
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: thanks, any tip on how to share the right ID for each process ?

Answer (score 2):

Here value  can be

```
'c': ctypes.c_char,  'u': ctypes.c_wchar,
'b': ctypes.c_byte,  'B': ctypes.c_ubyte,
'h': ctypes.c_short, 'H': ctypes.c_ushort,
'i': ctypes.c_int,   'I': ctypes.c_uint,
'l': ctypes.c_long,  'L': ctypes.c_ulong,
'f': ctypes.c_float, 'd': ctypes.c_double
```

and so the  initialization will be according to it.

but params num and args are mandatory .